# Read host name in web.xml file deployed on tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am doing URL redirection in my `web.xml` which deployed on tomcat ,so using hard coded URL with server name where I want to redirect .

for example I have `app1.war` and `app2.war` deployed on `serverOne`

I am redirecting some url pattern from app1 to `app2`  like serverOne//app2/login

everything is fine but after testing on server1 ,I have to move my app1 and app2 to `serverTwo`

so that time I have to modify `web.xml` to new url `serverTwo//app2/login` ,

The solution I am looking like where I can read current system host name  like

`$(hostname)/app2/login` 
so need to change my `web.xml` file while migrating from one server to another

#### EDIT:

Solved by creating variable in tomcat.conf file like we are using ${catlina.home} variable

Answer (score 0):

you can't do like this  for host multiple project in same tomcat than you need to add host name  in conf/server.xml file in tomcat . 
like this

```
  <Host name="abc.com"  appBase="webappsexample" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
              <Alias>abc.com</Alias> 
  </Host>
```

Comment: Solved by creating variable in tomcat.conf file like we are using ${catlina.home} variable